# How to disable a button until another button is clicked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write some jQuery to disable my registration button unless my survey button has been clicked (which opens a modal window). Can anyone help me?

I need users to click the popup survey button before they press the main registration button.

All I really have at the moment is the jQuery to disable the register button:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#registerButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The class for my survey button is: .btn-survey

Comment: Use prop to change the disabled state: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#registerButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $("#surveyButton").click(function(){
     $("#registerButton").removeAttr("disabled"); // removing attribute
   })
});
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thanks a lot, I was thinking I needed an if/else statement but this makes more sense for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just like how you disabled it in the first place.

```
$('.btn-survey').click(function() {
  $('#registerButton').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```